# View, view query definition, and physical base table counts mismatch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm wanting to get rid of unneeded deletes with no where clauses and while working through them, I ran across something that I can't quite figure out.

Selecting from the view produces 64895 results. However, pulling out the query from the definition and running it produces 863855 results. The view is not indexed and my login has sysadmin rights. I thought that maybe I missed something and the query was pulling distinct results but it is not. Adding to it, there isn't any filtering via a where clause.

Can someone tell me why these counts mismatch?

Below is the T-SQL stripped down a bit.

```
--Physical Table
SELECT  COUNT(1)
FROM    PhysicalTable
-- rowcount 863855
```

```
--View
SELECT  COUNT(1)
FROM    vw_PhysicalTable;
-- rowcount 64895
```

```
 --View Definition
 CREATE VIEW vw_PhysicalTable
 AS
 SELECT  PhysicalTable.[Column 0]
        ,PhysicalTable.[Column 1]
        ,PhysicalTable.[Column 2]
        ,PhysicalTable.[Column 3]
        ,PhysicalTable.[Column 4]
        ,PhysicalTable.[Column 5]
        ,PhysicalTable.[Column 6]
        ,PhysicalTable.[Column 7]
 FROM    PhysicalTable;
 GO
```

```
--Table Definition
CREATE TABLE PhysicalTable
    (
     [Column 0] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 1] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 2] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 3] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 4] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 5] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 6] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 7] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 8] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 9] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 10] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 11] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 12] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 13] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 14] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 15] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 16] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 17] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 18] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 19] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 20] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 21] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 22] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 23] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 24] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,[Column 25] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,SomeTime [DATETIME] NULL
    ,SomeSID [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                      NOT NULL
    ,SomeCode [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PhysicalTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( SomeSID ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90 ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY];
```

Comment: Somethings missing from the above.  looks like your view has  a join you're not sowing or a group by grouping sets or soemthing that would cause the rows to inflate.

Comment: Have you tried looking up just 1 of the rows thats missing? Possibility you are looking at a dev box and a prod box? Just brainstorming.

Comment: @xQbert That definition is pulled straight from the SSMS with object names changed.

Comment: @SQLChao I haven't been able to figure out which is missing yet, and I use SQL Prompt to color my environments and it is just DEV. Additionally, I have no linked servers.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being a simple gotcha. The table name was ambiguous and existed in multiple schemas. doh